# igraph edge width and color positive and negative correlation

Tags: r, igraph

I´m trying to plot an i graph using taxonomic information. The original correlation matrix is attached as a dput output.

[The original dput file correlation matrixe is found here](https://ufile.io/hf2wy)

My code looks like this. Assuming cor.matrix is the correlation matrix (see link to get it).

```
set.seed(123)

  t = which(abs(cor.matrix) > 0.6 & lower.tri(cor.matrix),arr.ind=TRUE)
  t.graph=graph.data.frame(t,directed=F)
  E(t.graph)$color =ifelse(cor.matrix[t] > 0.6,'magenta','green')

  t.names <- colnames(cor.matrix)[as.numeric(V(t.graph)$name)]
  minC <- rep(-Inf, vcount(t.graph))
  maxC <- rep(Inf, vcount(t.graph))
  minC[1] <- maxC[1] <- 0
  l <- layout_with_fr(t.graph, minx=minC, maxx=maxC,
                       miny=minC, maxy=maxC)      
  plot(t.graph, layout=l, 
       rescale=T,
       asp=0,
       edge.arrow.size=0.5, 
       vertex.label.cex=0.8, 
       vertex.label.family="Helvetica",
       vertex.label.font=2,
       vertex.label=t.names,
       vertex.shape="circle", 
       vertex.size=3, 
       vertex.color="deepskyblue2",
       vertex.label.color="black", 
       edge.width=0.5)
```

[image]

I would like to accomplish three different things:

1 - Have one color for positive and negative correlation.

2 - Change edge width, the higher the correlation (positive or negative) the thicker the edge.

3 - Have a graph easier to vew, it´s hard to view and identify nodes

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For points 1 and 2 you just need to pass a vector to the appropriate plotting argument. For edge color use `edge.color` and for edge width use `edge.width` you can also set an edge attribute in the graph object and igraph will automatically use that for plotting. The igraph manual specifies a lot of this: http://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html

As for point 3. The only way to make the graph more readable is to make plot it to a bigger canvas (i.e. increase the resolution) or remove some nodes. Graphs become notoriously hard to read as the number of nodes increases and there is nothing to do about it.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(123)

cor.matrix <- matrix(runif(100, -1, 1), nrow=10)

t = which(abs(cor.matrix) > 0.6 & lower.tri(cor.matrix),arr.ind=TRUE)
t <- cbind(t, cor.matrix[which(abs(cor.matrix) > 0.6 & lower.tri(cor.matrix),arr.ind=TRUE)]) ##this adds the correlation to the graph as an edge attribute "V3"
t.graph=graph.data.frame(t,directed=F)
E(t.graph)$color <- ifelse(E(t.graph)$V3 > 0,'magenta','green') #You had this as "V3 > 0.6" which I guess works but it is more readable as 0. that way if you decide to lower the correlation threshold you do not have to change this line too.

#t.names <- colnames(cor.matrix)[as.numeric(V(t.graph)$name)]
minC <- rep(-Inf, vcount(t.graph))
maxC <- rep(Inf, vcount(t.graph))
minC[1] <- maxC[1] <- 0
l <- layout_with_fr(t.graph, minx=minC, maxx=maxC,
                    miny=minC, maxy=maxC)      
plot(t.graph, layout=l, 
     rescale=T,
     asp=0,
     edge.arrow.size=0.5, 
     vertex.label.cex=0.8, 
     vertex.label.family="Helvetica",
     vertex.label.font=2,
     #vertex.label=t.names,
     vertex.shape="circle", 
     vertex.size=3, 
     vertex.color="deepskyblue2",
     vertex.label.color="black", 
     #edge.color=E(t.graph)$color, ##do not need this since E(t.graph)$color is already defined.
     edge.width=as.integer(cut(abs(E(t.graph)$V3), breaks = 5)))
```

[image]